# Apex Conditional Highlight with Data linked from another table

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, apex

I have two separate table that store data in Apex. The main table that feeds the report is current employees. The other table I have is essentially a list of terminated employees with other information on it.

I am trying to find a way that if a name stored in both tables, that row would show up red on the report.

I put this code as an SQL Query into the report query:

```
    select ID,
          PAINT_SHOP,
          "LOCKER_#",
          LOCKER_LOCATION,
          DEPT,
          ASSOCIATE_NUMBER,
          NAME__CINTAS_,
          AUDIT_NOTES_,
          LOCKER_TRANSFER_REQUESTED
     from LOCKER_AUDIT
     where (LOCKER_LOCATION = :P12_LL or :P12_LL is null)
     select
        NAME__CINTAS_,
            case when LOCKER_TERM_LIST.NAME = 'TERMINATED' then 'salmon' else 'black' end as event_color
    from Locker_Audit, LOCKER_TERM_LIST where LOCKER_AUDIT.NAME_CINTAS_ = LOCKER_TERM_LIST.NAME
```

*LOCKER_AUDIT --> Table for data storage of report
*LOCKER_TERM_LIST --> Table storing termed employee data

I am receiving this error:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option.  Say this is your report query:

```
select x.*
    ,case when y.employee_status = 'TERMINATED' then 'salmon' 
    else 'black' end as event_color
from current_employees x, old_employees y 
where y.employee_id = x.employee_id
```

Then from the content body, expand COLUMNS and look for the column you want to see in different color and click on it.

On the right frame you will see a text area called HTML Formatting.

Use some HTML there, like:

```
<span style="color:#EVENT_COLOR#">#YOUR_COLOURED_COLUMN#</span>
```

I think this would work.

Comment: Hey I updated the question to try and match the code you posted. I am receiving an error I am assuming very small, if you could look at it I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: you have one extra apostrophe after TERMINATED', remove that one.

Comment: That was just an error from me copy and pasting the code, I am unfortunately still receiving the same error

Comment: hi
you should prepare a fiddle for a better answer but you can't join 2 tables like this

perhaps this can help you finding your own solution:

select 
 x.*,
 case when y.NAME = 'TERMINATED' then 'salmon' else 'black' end as event_color
from LOCKER_AUDIT x, locker_term_list y
where (LOCKER_LOCATION = :P12_LL or :P12_LL is null)
and x.NAME_CINTAS = y.NAME

Comment: I am kind of lost on what the x and y's are for

Comment: they are aliases, you can name your tables as a,b,c or x,y,z